# SpringData query method with fixed criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have:

```
enum Status{
  OPEN,CLOSED;
}

class Foo{
  Status status;
}
```

How to create type-safe method for finding all Foos with status OPEN using Spring-Data MongoDB queries or please send me link on documentation =)

This is not fit for me

```
List<Foo> findByStatus(Status status)

@Query("{'status':'OPEN'}")
List<Position> findOpenFoos();
```